# Annoying SQLite Query issue with Expandable Listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a very annoying issue with one of my apps. When I release an update with an incremented version of the app and database.

The on Update is fired and the old database is deleted and the new is brought in. Below is the on update code

```
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS android_metadata");

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("sqlfile");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line  = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                db.execSQL(line); 
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }

    }
```

The expandable menu comes into this as you can click on a country and it will list all the rows in that country. The problem is that in the previous version this worked ok. But then when updated this will not work at all, but every other query works well. Below is the relevant query.

```
            protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {

                    String countryID = Integer.toString(groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
                    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

                    Cursor value = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE open='1' AND country=?", new String[]{countryID});

                    //checkDB.close();

                    return value;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

in the onUpdate, backup the database data into temporary tables, then drop the tables, and create the new ones. Fnally, copy back the old data.

**UPDATE :**

you could also backup the data to java variables via the cursors you open and when you create the new database, dump them back

Comment: what am i doing wrong at the moment. All I want to do is delete the old and import the new. Surely this is the same as your suggestion but cutting out the temporary tables

Comment: you are droping the tables, which is deleting its contents